# SQL select total and split into success and failed

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

```
Table 1                Table 2                   
|leadid|Location|      |leadid|leadstatus|       
|---------------|      |-----------------|
|1     |Japan   |      |1     | Hired    |
|2     |China   |      |2     | Failed   |
|3     |Korea   |      |3     | Hired    |
|4     |Japan   |      |4     | Hired    |
|5     |Japan   |      |5     | Hired    |
```

My objective is to count the number of interviews per country and also count the number of hires and failed in each country. The resulting table should be like this

```
|Location|Interview|Hired|Failed|
|-------------------------------|
|Japan   | 3       |3    |0     |
|Korea   | 1       |1    |0     |
|China   | 1       |0    |1     |
```

I have already done the counting of interviews per country. MY problem is I cannot count the number of hires and failed in each country.
Here is my MySQL code as of the moment:

```
SELECT Location, count(*) as Interview 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY Location 
ORDER BY Interview DESC
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT Location, COUNT(*) as Interview,
SUM(CASE WHEN leadstatus = 'Hired' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Hired,
SUM(CASE WHEN leadstatus = 'Failed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Failed
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.leadid = table2.leadid
            GROUP BY Location 
            ORDER BY Interview DESC
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49b07/8) is a working sqlfiddle.

EDIT 2019: This can be simplified without using case statements, as the conditional statement itself returns a 1 or a 0, so you can simply `SUM()` on that:

```
SELECT Location, COUNT(*) as Interview,
SUM(leadstatus = 'Hired') as Hired,
SUM(leadstatus = 'Failed') as Failed
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.leadid = table2.leadid
            GROUP BY Location 
            ORDER BY Interview DESC
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49b07/9) is the updated sqlfiddle.

Comment: What if want to apply the sum on only top 4 records?

Comment: @CodeQuestor Do a LEFT JOIN on a select query (Grabbing only the top 4 records) instead.

Answer (score 8):

You can use conditional sum along with ranking system using the user defined variable as

```
select
@rn:=@rn+1 as rank, 
location,
interview,
hired,
failed
from(
    select 
        t1.location, 
        count(*) as interview,
        sum(t2.leadstatus='Hired') as hired,
        sum(t2.leadstatus='Failed') as failed
        from table1 t1
        join table2 t2 on t1.leadid = t2.leadid 
        group by t1.location
        order by interview desc
)x,(select @rn:=0)y 
order by rank ;
```

Comment: why bother with the ranking? that's not a requirement of the question and isn't necessary to order the results.

Comment: Looks like the question is updated, where it was having some ranking.

Comment: ah. weird that you saw that version. makes sense now. although there's something weird about the voting on this question and the answers

Answer (score 5):

Have Tested This. Please find [SQL FIDDLE LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76eeb/1)

```
SELECT 

    t1.leadid, 
    t1.Location, 
    count( t2.leadstatus ) Location, 
    count(case when t2.leadstatus = 'Hired' then t2.leadstatus end) as Hired, 
    count(case when t2.leadstatus = 'Failed' then t2.leadstatus end) as Failed  

FROM table1 AS t1 
    INNER JOIN table2 AS t2  
    ON t1.leadid = t2.leadid 

GROUP BY t1.Location,t2.leadstatus 
Order BY Hired DESC
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76eeb/1)

Answer (score 4):

Simple conditional aggregation is all that is required here. As well as joining your two tables together:

```
select t1.location, count(*) as Interview, 
       count(case when t2.leadstatus = 'hired' then t2.leadstatus end) as Hired, 
       count(case when t2.leadstatus = 'failed' then t2.leadstatus end) as Failed
 from table1 t1
   inner join table2 t2
     on t1.leadid = t2.leadid
 group by t1.location
```

`count()` will only count non-null fields, and the `case` statement result is `null` when the condition is not met.  Handy technique that applies in a lot of use cases.

This will only include locations for which there has been at least one interview. If you wish to include all countries, change the `inner join` to a `left join`.

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/436685/2)

Answer (score 4):

```
Select location,count(*) as Interview,
SUM(CASE WHEN (status='Hired')Then 1 Else 0 END) as Hired,
SUM(CASE WHEN(status='Failed') Then 1 Else 0 END) as Failed 
from loc inner join status on loc.leadid= status.leadid 
group by location;
```

where first table is **loc** containg **leadid** and **location**,second table is **status** containing **leadid** and **status**

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT table1.location, COUNT(*) as Interview, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN table2.leadstatus = 'hired' THEN table2.leadstatus END) as Hired, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN table2.leadstatus = 'failed' THEN table2.leadstatus END) as Failed
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.leadid = table2.leadid
GROUP BY table1.location
ORDER BY Interview DESC;
```

fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/269da/14

Comment: where are you joining the two tables ??

Comment: do i need to use INNER JOIN to join the two tables?

Comment: Yes you need to but it seems incomplete table structure

Comment: table1 doesn't have `hired`, `failed` OR `interview` fields. how on earth does this get upvoted?